# netstat or alternative in docker ubuntu server 16.04 container

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, docker, netstat

Was `netstat` removed in `16.04`? Is there an alternative to `netstat` available in `16.04`? Or how do I install `netstat` in `16.04`?

I am running an `ubuntu:16.04` container in `docker for Windows`, it seems that `netstat` is no longer available... It is available in an `ubuntu:14.04` container.

I have tried installing netstat with `apt-get` but with no luck...

```
apt-get update
```

...

```
apt-get install netstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netstat
```

It might be that the solution to this is very obvious to most devs, however Linux is very new to me... enjoying it a lot!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

As you can see from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/net-tools/filelist, `netstat` is provided by the `net-tools` package. Therefore, you can get `netstat` by running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install net-tools
```

`net-tools` is probably not installed by default in the Docker image for Ubuntu 16.04 to keep the image size as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl. It seems though that netstat was included as default in 14.04. If it is not included as default in 16.04 do you know if an alternative is included as default in 16.04? Or was it not included in 16.04 simply to make 16.04 a more essential unit?

Comment: @DuncanGravill It is provided by default on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. It may have been excluded from the Docker image that you are using to keep the image size manageable. In any case, it is no big deal and you can just install it if it is missing.

Comment: Not only am I not able to find and install net-tools on 16.04 xenial ubuntu, I'm also not able to use sudo since they removed that from the docker image.

Nvm needed apt-get update

Answer (score 41):

In my opinion is better to begin adapting yourself to new tools.

`ss` is auto-defined as "another utility to investigate sockets"

```
ss -ltu
```

Will show listening sockets for tcp and udp.

For more information you can use `ss --help` or `man ss`.  The program `ss` can be found in the [`iproute2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/iproute2/filelist) package.

Comment: What about `nstat` , Is that a good one ?

Comment: Thanks. netstat is obsolete, you should use ss (man netstat)

Comment: netstat is deprecated for linux, but still used on other operating systems.  Good tip for use of ss.

Comment: Which apt package provides `ss`?

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 Please don't ask questions in the comments section. `iproute2` is what you are looking for.

Comment: how to list ssh tunnels using `ss`? I'm looking for an alternative to `netstat -tulpen` command.

Answer (score 2):

The version of ubuntu that's provided for use in containers has much less installed in it than a typical desktop installation.

Netstat is still available in Ubuntu 16.04 (via the net-tools package).  It's just that that package isn't installed inside docker containers by default.

Comment: It is not installed in Ubuntu 18.04 as well