# How to see the address dnsmasq is listening to without netstat

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, netstat

I used to run `sudo netstat -tulpen | grep dnsmasq`, but netstat is outdated. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/897861/596618) says to use `ss` as an alternative, but I cannot get the desired output. I.e. `ss -ltu | grep dnsmasq` does not print anything, despite dnsmasq being obviously running (my domain gets resolved).

Can I use ss to see dnsmasq's listening address? If so: How? If not: What is the non-deprecated alternative to netstat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo ss -ltup | grep dnsmasq
```

About your command: `ss -ltu`, The `-p` (*Show process using socket*) parameter is missing and `-p` requires `sudo`.

Comment: I tried `-ltup`, but without sudo, so thanks